# My python code which uses scipy is throwing a value error

Tags: python, scipy

I have the following question and I have coded the following for it:

```
def prob6():
"""Time regular and sparse linear system solvers.

For various values of n, generate the (n**2,n**2) matrix A described of
prob5() and vector b of length n**2. Time how long it takes to solve the
system Ax = b with each of the following approaches:

    1. Convert A to CSR format and use scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve()
    2. Convert A to a NumPy array and use scipy.linalg.solve().

In each experiment, only time how long it takes to solve the system (not
how long it takes to convert A to the appropriate format). Plot the system
size n**2 versus the execution times. As always, use log scales where
appropriate and use a legend to label each line.
"""
#raise NotImplementedError("Problem 6 Incomplete")

n = 2**np.arange(1,5)

time1 = []
time2 = []



for i in n:
    diagonals = [[1],[-4],[1]]
    offsets = [-1,0, 1]
    B = (sparse.diags(diagonals, offsets, shape=(i,i)))
    A = sparse.block_diag(([B]*i))
    A.setdiag(1,i)
    A.setdiag(1,-i)
    A.setdiag(1,-i)
    print(A.toarray())
    b = np.random.random(i*i)
    Acsr = A.tocsr()
    start = time.time()
    Acsr_final = spla.spsolve(A,b)
    time1.append(time.time() - start)

for i in n:
    diagonals = [[1],[-4],[1]]
    offsets = [-1,0, 1]
    B = (sparse.diags(diagonals, offsets, shape=(i,i)))
    A = sparse.block_diag(([B]*i))
    A.setdiag(1,i)
    A.setdiag(1,-i)
    A.setdiag(1,-i)
    A.toarray()
    b = np.random.random(i*i)
    Anpa = np.squeeze(np.asarray(A))
    start = time.time()
    Anpa_final = sp.linalg.solve(A,b)
    time2.append(time.time() - start)

plt.loglog(n, time1, 'm.-', lw=2, ms=15, label="time 1")
plt.loglog(n, time2, 'g.-', lw=2, ms=15, label="time 2")
plt.legend()
plt.title("Times regular and sparse linear system solvers")
plt.xlabel("n", fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel("Seconds", fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

prob6()

It keeps throwing the following ValueError on line 243 and I can't seem to solve it. It seems to have a problem with one of my scipy functions. I'm also not sure if what I've done is correct, so that may also be confusing things. Can anyone help?

```
ValueError: Sparse matrices are not supported by this function. Perhaps one of the scipy.sparse.linalg functions would work instead.
```

Comment: We can't see line numbers, please [edit] to include the full error traceback. The error is telling you that whatever function you're trying to use doesn't work with sparse matrices; what have you tried to solve it? Convert it to dense, try a different function, etc.?

Comment: The error message looks very informative. Apparently you are using a sparse matrix and are calling a function such as `scipy.linalg,solve` which complains it doesn't support sparse matrices. Furthermore, the error message suggests using a similar function from `scipy.sparse.linalg` if you need sparse matrices. You might want to read about the difference between sparse and dense matrices, for example [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/sparse-matrices-for-machine-learning/)